Writing a pandas dataframe to hdf creates an index even though I specified index=False. Why?
I have a dataframe in pandas I need to write to hdf using the df.to_hdf call. I have ensured that I don't have a column named  'Index' and I have put index=False in the call, but the index column appears in the output hdf file anyway. What am I missing? (I am using pandas version 1.5.1 and Python 3.9.12).
Here is the code to do the write:
df_total.to_hdf(os.path.join(target),key='Data', \ mode='w',format='table', index=False, data_columns = \ ('year','month','day','hour','min','sec','recno','kindat','kinst',\ 'ut1_unix','ut2_unix','call_sign_tx','txlat','txlon','call_sign_rx',\ 'rxlat','rxlon','tfreq','sn','smode','ssrc','pthlen','latcen','loncen') , \ complevel=9, complib='zlib')
I have tried this both with the columns explicitly listed as above, and letting it include all the columns. There is a screenshot of the HDFView showing the index was created even with index=False.

I have a lot of experience with pytables (used by Pandas to write HDF5 data). However, I limited knowledge of pandas and its code base. So, I had to research the index=False behavior as related to your request.
TL; DR: It appears to me that an index column is always written to the dataset. The index=False parameter only controls whether or not another group (and related datasets) are added to the dataset with indexing data (group name: _i_table). In other words, I don't think there is a way to get the behavior you want.
To diagnose this, I used a slightly modified version of an example I found in the Pandas docs. Ref: HDF5 Indexing. Run the code below, then examine the H5 file contents with HDFView:
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 2), columns=list("AB"))
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 2), columns=list("AB"))

with pd.HDFStore("pd_appends_example.h5", mode="w") as st:
    st.append("df", df_1, data_columns=["A", "B"], index=False)
    st.append("df", df_2, data_columns=["A", "B"], index=False)

Notice that the only object in the file is a group named df that contains a dataset named table (with 3 columns: index, A, B).
Next, run the code below. (Remember to close HDFView before you do).
with pd.HDFStore("pd_appends_example.h5", mode="a") as st:    
    st.create_table_index("df", columns=["B"], optlevel=9, kind="full")

Examine the H5 file again, and notice the df group now has another object: a group named _i_table with a subgroup named B which contains several datasets used for indexing. I'm 99.44% sure that's what the index parameter controls. If you initally leave index=False off (or set to True), you will get the _i_table group. (Note: this code uses HDFStore. My tests show df.to_hdf() behaves identically).
I also found 2 enhancement requests on the pandas GitHub site that reinforce my conclusion:

ENH: add option to HDFStore.put/append to optionally store the index
of the object This is a request to add a write_index parameter to control writing the index column to the table. Status shows it was removed from the Someday milestone in 2022 (e.g., not implemented).
Resume existing index when appending to a HDFStore This enhancement is about the Index value written to the dataset when appending data (suggests the index values are always written). Status shows it was removed from Contributions Welcome in 2022.

